# Wordpress plugin add_settings_field exact code works in one instance but not in a second instance?

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a plugin making admin options pages using the combo "register_setting", "add_settings_section", "add_settings_field". I have a parent menu and 2 sub-menus. Making admin pages in Wordpress is pretty straight forward... it starts when you make the admin page. Here are my parameters for it. (this is done in OOP)

```
            'parent_slug' => 'Tee_Off', 
            'page_title' => 'Tee-Off Reports', 
            'menu_title' => 'Tee-Off Reports', 
            'capability' => 'manage_options', 
            'menu_slug' => 'tee_offs_reports', 
            'callback' => 'path to my template file goes here'; //this is correct in my code
```

so remember my menu slug "tee_offs_reports" posted above is needed for the next step...

```
    class ClubHouseReports
{
    function register()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'teeoff_report_sellector') );
        
    }
    
    function teeoff_report_sellector() {
        register_setting( 'my_options_group', 'timer_month' );
        register_setting( 'my_options_group', 'timer_day' );
        register_setting( 'my_options_group', 'timer_year' );
        
        add_settings_section( 'teeoff-club-options', 'Get Monthy Report', array( $this,     'teeoff_month_section'), 'tee_offs_reports');
        
        add_settings_field( 'timer_month', 'Month', array( $this, 'teeoff_month'), 'tee_offs_reports', 'teeoff-club-options');
        add_settings_field( 'timer_day', 'Day', array( $this, 'teeoff_day'), 'tee_offs_reports', 'teeoff-club-options');
        add_settings_field( 'timer_year', 'Year', array( $this, 'teeoff_year'), 'tee_offs_reports', 'teeoff-club-options');
        
    }
    function teeoff_month_section() {
        echo '<p>Reports</p>';
                
    }

    function teeoff_month() {
        $timer_month = esc_attr( get_option( 'timer_month' ) );
        echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="timer_month" value="'.$timer_month.'" placeholder="Month" />';      
    }
    function teeoff_day() {
        $timer_day = esc_attr( get_option( 'timer_day' ) );
        echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="timer_day" value="'.$timer_day.'" placeholder="Day" />';        
    }
    function teeoff_year() {
        $timer_year = esc_attr( get_option( 'timer_year' ) );
        echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="timer_month" value="'.$timer_year.'" placeholder="Year" />';        
    }
    }
```

This class above is being call from the root plugin file, just like the one that works. An instance is made then the method "register()" is called.

In my template file I do this.... just like the one that does work.

```
    <?php settings_errors(); ?>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'my_options_group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections('teeoff-club-options'); ?>
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
```

SO my problem is... except for where the values need to change when you repeat the same code, in this case like, you need to assign a new menu slug, a new name for the "register_setting", and making sure it's aiming at the right callback, which I assure you everything is set right... for some reason this wont render.

I get no errors, all I see is the submit button, and if I use it I get a "success" message, so everything is in scope... but nothing is rendering on the "tee_offs_reports" page except for the submit  button... which makes sense since it's hard coded there.

All this to say... I went over my code dozens of time to look for the smallest/stupidiest syntax mistake, or anything why this admin area wont work, while the other which uses the exact same structure and logic, works 100%. Do you see anything wrong with this code? Don't mind the big space between code above, that only happened when I pasted it here.... Is there a restriction in wordpress that I don't know of yet? Why is this not working? While a blue print of it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I'm really baffled... I got it to work, but I highly doubt I'm following the codex rules... or am I?????

here is the code that is working 100%

```
function teeoff_report_sellector() {
        register_setting( 'my_options_group', 'timer_month' );
        register_setting( 'my_options_group', 'timer_day' );
        register_setting( 'my_options_group', 'timer_year' );
        
        add_settings_section('tee-off-reports', 'Get Monthy Report', array( $this, 'teeoff_month_section'), 'tee-off-reports');
        
        add_settings_field('timer_month', 'Month', array( $this, 'teeoff_month'), 'tee-off-reports', 'tee-off-reports');
        add_settings_field('timer_day', 'Day', array( $this, 'teeoff_day'), 'tee-off-reports', 'tee-off-reports');
        add_settings_field('timer_year', 'Year', array( $this, 'teeoff_year'), 'tee-off-reports', 'tee-off-reports');
        
    }
    function teeoff_month_section() {
        echo '<p>Reports</p>';
                
    }

    function teeoff_month() {
        $timer_month = esc_attr( get_option( 'timer_month' ) );
        echo '<input type="date" class="regular-text" name="timer_month" value="'.$timer_month.'" placeholder="Month" />';      
    }
    function teeoff_day() {
        $timer_day = esc_attr( get_option( 'timer_day' ) );
        echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="timer_day" value="'.$timer_day.'" placeholder="Day" />';        
    }
    function teeoff_year() {
        $timer_year = esc_attr( get_option( 'timer_year' ) );
        echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="timer_year" value="'.$timer_year.'" placeholder="Year" />';     
    }
```

What I did is... instead of using the menu slug like the codex tells you to do, ...(and the first admin page I created works well that way) I replaced that by the "add_settings_section" ID... so if you look at the before last parameter for each "add_settings_field" they are now assigned the ID of the section, codex is supposed to be looking for the menu slug... I always thought anyways... again the first one I did, works awesome that way... so the 2 last parameters of the "add_settings_field" are the same. Weird! Nowhere is the page slug mention in the code above, yet this works 100% and does not break any other code.

Now I'm wondering... did I find a bug in the Settings API? that will be fixed later on, and my plugin is going to stop working? Or did I stumble on the solution by being desperate trying a whole bunch of stuff???

I don't get it... if there's a real WordPress guru out there that can explain this to me I would be very appreciative!